# Post loop count is not in order

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, advanced-custom-fields, count

I am using custom post type. But on landing page Count of post loop is not in order

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'focus-areas' ,'get' => 'all') );  ?>

        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $counts++; ?>
<?php echo $counts; ?>
```

This printing as 16, 1, 3, 4, 5,....

All the post are getting display but it's not in order. i searched in google and wordpress site but din't get any solution

Comment: `get` is not a valid parameter for `WP_Query`. That does nothing. Where did you get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** Try to initialize the `$count` variable before your loop:

```
$counts=0;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'focus-areas', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );  
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    $counts++; 
    echo $counts;
    echo " - "; 
endwhile;
```

**b)** or use the `current_post` method (starts at `0`) of `WP_Query`:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'focus-areas', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );  
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    echo $loop->current_post; 
    echo " - "; 
endwhile;
```

### Results:

On my install where I have 12 posts in a custom post type, case **a)** gives me:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 -
```

and case **b)** gives:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 -
```

**ps:** I'm not sure what you mean by `'get' => 'all'` but the usual way of fetching all posts is to use `'posts_per_page' => -1`

Comment: 'get' => 'all' means i get all the post from the post type. Wordpress can display 10 post by default. 
i tried echo $loop->current_post; but still same result;

Comment: the usual way is to use `'posts_per_page' => -1` to get all posts. I updated the answer with my results.